# Differentiating Vectors Using Chain Rule: Textbook Clarification

Tags: multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

My textbook has the following:

[image]

My question is, isn't the chain rule $\dfrac{ \partial{f} }{ \partial{g} } \dfrac{ dg }{ dt } + \dfrac{ \partial{f} }{ \partial{h} } \dfrac{ dh }{dt }$?

Comment: Du you mean $\frac{\partial f}{\partial h}$ in the last line?

Comment: @trancelocation Yes, thank you very much.

Comment: The point is that $f$ is a function of $x$ and $y$. So no, you don't differentiate with respect to $g$ or $h$. This is a remnant of *bad* single-variable notation.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ok, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it becomes clearer if you set:

- $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$

instead of

- $x=g(t)$ and $y=h(t)$.

So it is just using different symbols.

Comment: But it *did* set $x=g(t)$ and $y=h(t)$, so wouldn't it be correct to use my version instead?

Comment: Both are correct as long as one knows what is meant.

Comment: Ok, understood. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You are welcome.